# Passing php array to javascript then accessing values by key

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm using $.post to return an array from a separate php file, and trying to access the values of the array in javascript by the keys, but am having trouble doing so.

Here's the post code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var limRefresh  = setInterval(refreshLIM, 10000);
var dbAction    = "feedRefresh";
var newestRow   = <?php echo $newestRow ?>;

$.post("jsDb.php",{ action: dbAction,lastRow: newestRow },function(status){
   console.log(status);
   console.log(newArr['status']);
   console.log(newArr.status);
   console.log(newArr[0]);
});

});
```

Here's the excerpt of how the response is being formatted in the external php file:

```
echo json_encode(array("status" => "success","actId" => $newActId));
```

And here's the respective console logs (just trying different options):

- {"status":"success","actId":"585924418"}
- undefined
- undefined
- {

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: where is `newArr` defined?

Comment: where did you decode your json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response you get as status from $.post is a string. You need to parse it order to use it as you intend. Moreover, newArr is undefined because you have not defined it anywhere. This is probably because you have reused someone else's code and missed this part:

```
newArr = JSON.parse(status)
```

Answer (score 1):

The response is coming as string, so you need to parse it before you can access it as JSON:

```
$.post("jsDb.php",{ action: dbAction,lastRow: newestRow },function(status){
  var data = JSON.parse(status);
  console.log(data['status'])
  console.log(data['actId'])
}
```